# How to create a structure with embedded fields?

Tags: c#, database, structure

I am looking for information about that in the internet but with no success. The goal is to realize a sort of dataset of 10 subject (sub_1, sub_2... sub_10), each of them has done 3 kind of activities (walk, run, jump) for three time each (trial_1... trial_3) with relative scores. I would like to access these information like:

```
variable = dataset.sub_1.jump.trial_2.score;
```

or, at least:

```
variable = dataset.sub[0].task[2].trial[1].score;
```

So, the structure would be a tree structure. Until now I only realized a structure with "parallel fields":

```
struct dataset
{
    public string[] sub;   // 1 to 10 subjects
    public string[] task;  // 1 to 3 tasks
    public string[] trial; // 1 to 3 trials
    public int score;      // the score of the above combination
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved in many ways.
My solution has one drawback, there is no check if user exceeded Score arrays capacity.

I guess database tag has nothing to do with this question

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public abstract class Task
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TotalScore { get { return Score.Sum(); } }
        public int[] Score { get; set; } = new int[3];
    }

    public class Walk : Task { }
    public class Run : Task { }
    public class Jump : Task { }

    public class Subject
    {
        public Walk Walk { get; set; } = new();
        public Run Run { get; set; } = new();
        public Jump Jump { get; set; } = new();
        public int TotalScore { get { return Walk.TotalScore + Run.TotalScore + Jump.TotalScore; }}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subject = new Subject();

            // Adding score to specific trials
            subject.Run.Score[0] = 50;
            subject.Run.Score[1] = 40;
            subject.Run.Score[2] = 60;

            subject.Jump.Score[0] = 40;
            subject.Jump.Score[1] = 80;
            subject.Jump.Score[2] = 100;

            // Output score of 1. trial for Walk task
            Console.WriteLine(subject.Walk.Score[0]);

            // Output total score as a sum of all trials for Jump task
            Console.WriteLine(subject.Jump.TotalScore);

            // Output total score as a sum of all trials in all tasks
            Console.WriteLine(subject.TotalScore);

            // ERROR CASE: this will be exception
            subject.Jump.Score[3] = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Trial
    {
        public Trial(int score)
        {
            Score = score;
        }

        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public List<Trial> Trials { get; } = new List<Trial>();
    }

    public class Subject
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Task> Tasks { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

        public Subject()
        {
            Tasks.Add("walk", new Task());
            Tasks.Add("run", new Task());
            Tasks.Add("jump", new Task());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Subject player1 = new Subject();

            player1.Tasks["run"].Trials.Add(new Trial(score: 3));

            Console.WriteLine(player1.Tasks["run"].Trials[0].Score);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe a class for everything is too much, but maybe you want to add a description property for tasks one day or a timestamp for the trial. Then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Subject
{
    private Dictionary<string,Activity> _activities { get; }= new Dictionary<string, Activity>();

    public Activity this[string activity]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_activities.Keys.Contains(activity))
                _activities[activity] = new Activity();
            return _activities[activity];
            
        }
        set
        {
                _activities[activity] = value;
        }

    } 
    public int Score => _activities.Values.Sum(x => x.Score);
}

public class Activity
{
    private Dictionary<int, Trial> _trials { get; } = new Dictionary<int, Trial>();
    public Trial this[int trial]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_trials.Keys.Contains(trial))
                _trials[trial] = new Trial();
            return _trials[trial];
        }
        set
        {
                _trials[trial] = value;
        }

    }
    public int Score => _trials.Values.Sum(x => x.Score);
}

public class Trial
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

        Subject Mindy = new Subject();
        Mindy["curling"][1].Score = 5;
        Mindy["bowling"][1].Score = 290;
        Console.WriteLine(Mindy.Score);
    }
}
```

This is what I would guess you think you need... but from your question I think you're still new to C# and might want to rethink your concept. It looks like a very database-oriented way of looking at the problem, so maybe you might want to take a look at dapper to more closely match your database.

Also, avoid using the classname Task, this can imo only cause confusion if you ever start using multithreading (System.Threading.Task is a .NET framework component)